# Is the zero truncated Poisson Distribution part of the Exponential Family?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, exponential-function, self-learning, poisson-distribution

This is the density of a truncated Poisson: 
$$P(X = x \mid X > 0) =  
\frac{\lambda ^ x e^{- \lambda} }{x ! \left ( 1 - e^{- \lambda} \right )}$$

To show that it's member of the Exponential family I have to bring it in this form:

Exponential family:

$ f(x, \theta, \phi) = exp ( \frac{ x \theta - b(\theta}{ a(\phi)} + c(x, \phi ))  $

if I do this for the Poisson distribution I get: $$ \theta = log \lambda \\ 
\lambda = e^\theta \\ b(\theta)= e^\theta \\ a(\phi)=1 \\ c(x,\phi)= -log(x!)$$
I struggle now with this extra term $ \frac{1}{1-e^{-\lambda}}$ from the truncated Poisson. Where does it belong to?

Comment: Asked and answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/409034/is-the-zero-truncated-poisson-distribution-part-of-the-exponential-family.

Comment: Consider posting an answer to your question in case you intend to keep the post. That removes it from the unanswered queue.